# How to find a regex pattern after a specific number of characters

Tags: regex, go

I need to search for a regex pattern after `n` characters in my Go program.
This is what I have tried so far. I have a string and I am trying match the pattern after n = 3 characters. I need to implement this via a regex pattern itself, instead of slicing strings.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    str := "abcdefgh"
    rx := regexp.MustCompile(`\A[^.{3}]d`)
    matched := rx.FindString(str)
    fmt.Println(matched)

    // expecting output as `d`
    // In regex, `\A` should start the regex check at the start of the string
    // In regex, `[^.{3}]` should mean that match any 3 characters at start and then skip them
    // in regex, `d` should mean that match only d
    // but I am not getting d. Something is not working as expected
}
```

Comment: Try `^.{3}(e)`. The start string character only makes sense at the start. Note you still won't match since `e` is the 5th character not the 4th.

Comment: Thanks. But (`^.{3}(d)`) returns `abcd`. I want only a match with `d`

Comment: You need to find the group and not the whole match

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which regular expression grammar you're used to working with, but this doesn't work in Go. The regular expression you should be using is:

```
regexp.MustCompile(`^.{3}(d)`)
```

This will inform Go to match any string in which the fourth character is a "d" and that it should match the "d" specifically.

Next, you don't want to use `FindString` because that will return the piece of the string that matches the regular expression, which would be "abcd" in this case. Instead, you should use `FindStringSubmatch`, which will return the match groups as they occur. Since you're looking for the first subgroup, you'll want the 1st match group:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    str := "abcdefgh"
    rx := regexp.MustCompile(`^.{3}(d)`)
    matched := rx.FindStringSubmatch(str)[1]
    fmt.Println(matched)
}
```